# [SOLVED]: Tkinter: Button Takes All The Column

Tags: python, tkinter

[I expect that the buttons and writings will be underneath each other in a certain order, but this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn2fA.png)

[My Expections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Lm9.png)

I Used Pack() To Order It .

EDITED:
This Is My Code

```
    orders_frame.pack_propagate(0)
    orders_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    for i in range(10):
        label = Label(orders_frame.interior, text="ABC")
        button = Button(orders_frame.interior, text="+").pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=N,expand=NO)
        button = Button(orders_frame.interior, text="+").pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=N,expand=NO)
        label.pack(side=TOP, anchor=N, fill=X, expand=NO)
```

Comment: I have no idea how you expect anybody to be able to help you, when you haven't shown any code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to directly include a [mcve].

Comment: Please don't put [SOLVED] in the title but accept the answer (click on the tick mark below the score) that solved your problem (or post your own answer if you did something different).

Answer (score 1):

You can put the label and the two buttons in a frame:

```py
for i in range(10):
    f = Frame(orders_frame.interior)
    f.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    tk.Button(f, text="+").pack(side=RIGHT)
    tk.Button(f, text="+").pack(side=RIGHT)
    tk.Label(f, text="ABC").pack(side=TOP)
```

It is the result:

[image]

---

Or you use `grid` instead of `pack` if you can.

Comment: i don't know how my work will done without you

Comment: @OmarEssam You are appreciated to accept it as the answer by clicking the *tick* beside the answer.

Comment: Im New I Cant Do That : )

Comment: But 1 Minute , I Cant Use The Scroll Bar That I Have Add It